# Sorting items by a dynamic discount, with pagination in Node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my code for a route on my Node.js backend which fetches items with pagination because otherwise the fetch is very slow. In it I also call a discount calculation function which calculates the item availability given the user entered eventDate, then calculates the discount for that item based off the item availability. The issue is I need to sort all the items within a category by their discount, but as of right now I can only sort the items in each page. Any ideas for how I can get the sorting to work?

```
//Route for items with limiting in fetch
app.get('/api/items', async (req, res) => {
  // let { category, eventDate} = req.query;

  let { category, page = 1, limit = 5 , eventDate} = req.query;

  if (category) {
    category = decodeURIComponent(category);
  }

  try {
    // Create a query object based on whether a category is provided
    const query = category ? { Category: category } : {};

    const items = await Item.find(query)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .limit(limit);


    const totalCount = await Item.countDocuments(query);

    // Prepare an array of promises to calculate availability and discounts for each item
    const availabilityAndDiscountPromises = items.map(async (item) => {
      const { availableQuantity, discountsApplied } = await calculateDiscountsAndAvailability(item, eventDate);
      return {
        ...item.toObject(),
        AvailableQuantity: availableQuantity,
        DiscountsApplied: discountsApplied,
      };
    });


    // Resolve all promises to get the final list of items with calculated availability and discounts
    let itemsWithAvailabilityAndDiscounts = await Promise.all(availabilityAndDiscountPromises);

    itemsWithAvailabilityAndDiscounts.sort((a, b) => {
      const bDiscount = b.DiscountsApplied && b.DiscountsApplied.length > 0 ? b.DiscountsApplied[0].discountPercentage : 0;
      const aDiscount = a.DiscountsApplied && a.DiscountsApplied.length > 0 ? a.DiscountsApplied[0].discountPercentage : 0;
      return bDiscount - aDiscount; // Descending order
    });

    res.json({
      data: itemsWithAvailabilityAndDiscounts,
      totalItems: totalCount,
      totalItems: totalCount,
      currentPage: Number(page),
      totalPages: Math.ceil(totalCount / limit),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during items fetch:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});
```

I tried fetching all the items, then calculating the discount, then sorting, but this slowed my website too much.

Comment: How did you try to sort the query results?